# Java Applet java.security.AccessControlException error

Tags: java, accesscontrolexception

I have a java applet that errors out sometimes with some attempts to load it, not always though. I am running JRE 1.7.0_03 on my local machine. The applet is running in a web application on IE version 9.0.8112.16421. The error has only occured when the user is not an administrator on the computer. We suspect the error is due to a java.security.AccessControlException. There is an Oracle bug reported for this issue https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6995087. Is there a way I can fix this on my end, or a workaround I can do to not have this issue?